# How to reduce "each" steps?

Tags: jquery

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/2hJPH/) :

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>            
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>    
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>            
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="child">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

$('.child').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('childParent');
    console.log("step");
});?
```

but as you can see, it `addClass` 7 times, which is not necessary. Is it possible reduce each step? In fact, on this example, is sufficent `addClass` only twice.

Comment: It seems like the most intuitive and efficient selector would be to select the parent right from the beginning.

Comment: do you need to do anything else within each "step" ?

Comment: Why not for each `parent` check it has a `child` if it does add the class - only two eaches, only two adds?

Answer (score 14):

Yes: just call `.parent()` on the collection. Elements will not be duplicated in a jQuery collection

```
$('.child').parent().addClass('childParent');
```

Comment: do you have a reference for your assertion about duplicate elements?

Comment: @Alnitak It takes some following, but the key expression is `jQuery.unique(ret)` on [line 215 of traversing.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L215).

Comment: @lonesomeday That was real fast to look up into that reference.

Comment: @Vega You just need to know where to look ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak if you read the docu carefully, you will see that they always speak of `set`s which is a fixed expression for a collection of unique elements.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the approach from the other answers is better, but this is an alternative if you actually need to keep the `.each()` call for whatever reason.

---

You could use the [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector to make sure only one `.child` element is selected per parent:

```
$('.child:first-child').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('childParent');
    console.log("step");
});
```

Now, it will only select 2 elements (the first `.child` element in each of your `.parent` elements), so the `.each()` call will only have two elements to iterate over.

Comment: Why here is called 2 times? http://jsfiddle.net/2hJPH/4/ it must be called 3 times...

Comment: Because there are only 2 elements that match the `:first-child` part of the selector. The last `.child` element is not the first child of anything. It's the last child of the outer `div`.

Comment: Uhm? inside that outer div, is the .child:first-child element :O This is my scenario, how can I do it?

Comment: Use the answer by @lonesomeday then. That will work. I've added some comments to show why what you had didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/2hJPH/5/

Comment: Yeah, but this will call "parent" for each child, which will be heavy if I have many child inside the same div...

Comment: I don't think you really have a choice, since not all the elements you want to target will match `:first-child`. Effectively, you will need to match some random element from each parent. There's no way to know which one, so you need to iterate over all of them. @lonesomeday has the best solution for your needs.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I opened this question! This is not the solution, is a fat workaround! Still I don't understand why your solution shouldn't work : in fact it makes sense....

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you're not just referencing the parent directly?

```
$('div.parent').addClass('childParent');
```

Comment: Maybe in the real application the parents don't always have the same class.

Comment: That's true.  I guess lonesomeday's comment was the main point.  The jquery select should return all of the elements.  Each() is only needed from there when you want to do something different each time.  If you're doing the same thing to all, let jquery handle unique().

Comment: Actually, in this case I suspect they actually are all the same class, but he doesn't want to add the `childParent` class to parents with no children. Is there a selector for that?

Comment: This might be what you're trying to accomplish: 

    $('div.parent:has(div.child)').addClass('childParent');

Comment: Then again, what lonesome day has should also work.  Here is what they wrote:    $('.child').parent().addClass('childParent');

Answer (score 0):

While you could call each child and then have jquery use a unique method, it probably isn't the most efficient use.  If for example there are 10 children for every parent, that means it would take 10x as long or longer as it has to select each child then check to see if it is unique.

Instead, only select parents to limit your initial select and then filter those using the "has()" method.  That would look something like this:

```
$('div.parent:has(div.child)').addClass('childParent');
```